# Partially specializing on non-type template parameter of the wrong type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, type-parameter

Consider the following:

```
template <unsigned >
struct uint_ { };

template <class >
struct X {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <int I> // NB: int, not unsigned
struct X<uint_<I>> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(X<uint_<0>>::value, "!");
}
```

clang compiles the code, gcc does not.

However, in the following highly related example:

```
template <unsigned >
struct uint_ { };

template <int I> // NB: int, not unsigned
void foo(uint_<I> ) { }

int main() {
    foo(uint_<0>{} );
}
```

both compilers reject with no matching function call to `foo`. gcc's behavior is consistent, clang's is not - so one or the other compiler has a bug for one or both examples. Which compiler is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC is correct. [[temp.deduct.type]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#17):

> If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of the
>   corresponding value of `A` differs from the type of `i`, deduction fails.